# How can I free an array of pointers where each pointer points to an address of a string which I allocated inside of a function?

Tags: c, pointers

How can I free an array of pointers where each pointer points to an address of a string which I allocated inside of a function?

I created a simple array of pointers, `*pointers[]`, inside my `main` and I'm passing it to `readline` which returns the amount of lines I have read.

The purpose of this is to store all the lines of the input separated by `'\n'`. Each line is stored in a pointer in the array of pointers.

So after `readline` is called and it returns, I can `printf("%s", pointers[0])` which will show the first line the user typed in.

The way I assign a line to each pointer in my array is inside `readline` by allocating a `char` pointer, `*p`, to have `MAXLENGTH` sizes and passing the current address of `p` to the respective pointer. After each assignment is done, I jump to the next free address of `p`.

Finally, my question is if I have to free (and how) my array of pointers after the `readline` routine is complete and I have printed all the lines stored.

I'll leave the two functions, `main` and `readline`, here for you.

```
#define NUMOFLINES 5
#define MAXLENGTH 1000

void main(void) {
    char *pointers[NUMOFLINES]; // Array of pointers to string
    int nlines;                 // Number of pointers read

    nlines = readlines(pointers);
    writelines(pointers, nlines);
    
/* FAILED ATTEMPT TO FREE THE ARRAY OF POINTERS */
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nlines ; i++)
        free(pointers[i]);
}

int readlines(char *pointers[]) {
    char line[MAXLENGTH];
    char *p;

    int iptr, len;
    
    /* ALLOCATE P */
    p = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXLENGTH); 

    for(iptr = 0 ; iptr < NUMOFLINES && (len = get_line(line)) > 0 ; iptr++) 
    {               
        strcpy(p, line);    // copy the line to the array, ending in len-th position
        pointers[iptr] = p; // Pass current adress 'p' to the respectively index of pointers
        p += len+1;         // Next free adress in array p
    }

    return iptr;
}
```

As you can see I tried to free by going through each pointer and calling `free(pointer[i]`, but all I get is

```
malloc(): corrupted top size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Do I need to call `free`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `malloc()` is done once outside of the loop. But you are doing `NUMOFLINES` times the free. I dont really get the purpose of `p += len+1;` here too.

Comment: I edited the question explaining that after I get one line I store the line in a pointer inside the array and after I jump to the next free available space inside `p` by doing `p = len+1`.
note that `len` is from "length", the input line length.


`p` here is merely an kind of a buffer that I store all the lines separated by `\0` It may not be the perfect code, I know, but is just for practicing as I still learning the essentials.

Comment: Just do `if ( nlines > 0 ) free(pointers[0]);` instead of the loop. In the function you should also check for not exceeding the size of space that was allocated

Comment: Can you clarify your answer? If I do `free(pointers[0])` it will free all the pointers?

Comment: @MatheusSpiazzi You are not `malloc()`ing each pointer, so there is no need to `free()` each pointer. See the answer I posted.

Comment: @spiazzy `free` frees a memory block, not a pointer *per se*. You only have one memory block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only call `malloc` once, so you should only call `free` once.

After `readlines` returns, `pointers[0]` points to the start of the memory you allocated, while the remaining array members point someplace *within* that same block of memory.  That means there's only one pointer to free.

So instead of this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < nlines ; i++)
    free(pointers[i]);
```

Just do this:

```
free(pointers[0]);
```

To reiterate, you should only pass to `free` a pointer value that was returned from `malloc` (or `realloc` or `calloc`).

Comment: So, if I understand correctly: if `pointers[0]` points to the beginning of the memory space I allocated inside my function, I just need to call `free` to the beginning of that memory space (in this case `pointers[0]`), is that right?. An extra question if you do not mind, I need to do `free(pointers)`  after?

Comment: @spiazzy That's correct.  And no you don't need to `free(pointers)` because it's an array local to the `main` function, not a pointer to allocated memory.

Comment: Makes perfectly sense and much more simple than i thought, I'll highlight your answer, thank u

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `malloc()` only 1 time, but you are calling `free()` multiple times.  Every `char*` in your array points within that single `malloc()`'ed memory block.  You can only call `free()` 1 time on the starting address of that block.  Calling `free()` on addresses inside the block is *undefined behavior*.

Also, the memory block you are allocating with `malloc()` is not nearly large enough, assuming each string that `get_line()` outputs can be up to `MAXLENGTH` characters.  You are only allocating enough memory for the maximum length of 1 single line, so as soon as your reading loop has copied `MAXLENGTH` characters into the allocated block, you are advancing your `p` pointer beyond the bounds of the block, causing subsequent `strcpy()`'s to write into and corrupt random memory.

If you want to stay with a single `malloc()` and sub-divide it, try something more like this instead:

```c
#define NUMOFLINES 5
#define MAXLENGTH 1000

int main(void) {
    char *pointers[NUMOFLINES], *buffer;

    int nlines = readlines(pointers, &buffer);
    if (nlines < 0) return -1;

    writelines(pointers, nlines);    

    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}

int readlines(char *pointers[], char **buffer) {
    *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (NUMOFLINES * MAXLENGTH));
    if (*buffer == NULL) return -1;

    int iptr, len;
    char *p = *buffer;
    
    for(iptr = 0; (iptr < NUMOFLINES) && ((len = get_line(p)) > 0); ++iptr) 
    {               
        pointers[iptr] = p;
        p += len + 1;
    }

    return iptr;
}
```

Otherwise, I suggest you allocate a separate buffer for each pointer in the array, eg:

```c
#define NUMOFLINES 5
#define MAXLENGTH 1000

int main(void) {
    char *pointers[NUMOFLINES];

    int nlines = readlines(pointers);
    if (nlines < 0) return -1;

    writelines(pointers, nlines);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < nlines; ++i)
        free(pointers[i]);

    return 0;
}

int readlines(char *pointers[]) {
    char line[MAXLENGTH], *p;
    int iptr, len;

    for(iptr = 0; (iptr < NUMOFLINES) && ((len = get_line(line)) > 0); ++iptr)
    {               
        p = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
        if (p == NULL) {
            for(int j = 0; j < iptr; ++j) free(pointers[j]);
            return -1;
        }

        memcpy(p, line, sizeof(char) * len);
        p[len] = '\0';
        pointers[iptr] = p;
    }

    return iptr;
}
```

Comment: The function puts each string consecutively in the same buffer , delimited by null terminator. The pointers point to each string (not all to the start of the buffer)

Comment: @M.M I know what the function is doing. I have updated my answer to reflect this better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to free the other pointers you maintain within your buffer. If you do a single

```
p = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXLENGTH);
```

then you need a single

```
free(p);
```

The `malloc` and `free` have to match exactly 1-to-1 and be called with the same addresses.

Since you want to modify `p`, you should do:

```
char* original = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXLENGTH);
p = original;
```

and, once done:

```
free(original)
```

Comment: I get it. But if I free(original) I'm not able to print all the lines, because I'm freeing what the pointers points to, right?

Comment: `free(original)` would be a mistake as then the caller has a bunch of dangling pointers

Comment: You can only free once you are completely done with the memory, after the prints

Comment: @Jeffrey the printing occurs after `readlines` returns, so `original` will no longer exist . (assuming your suggestion was that `char* original` be declared inside `readlines` -- if that is not the case then please clarify your answer)